# Do any compilers currently support C++20?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, c++20

I purchased a book recently entitled beginning C++20. I was looking to begin learning C++ though I now realize that I can't find a compiler that can run the code in the book as I get an error since the compiler I'm using (Xcode) does not support C++20. I'm wondering if there are any compilers that I can run on my mac that support C++20.

Comment: xcode's an IDE, not a compiler. The three major compilers (GCC, MSVC, and Clang) all support most but not all of C++20. You can find a summary table [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support)

Comment: Xcode 12 (and 13 Beta) includes a version of Clang that supports most of C++20 features. You just have to manually enter `c++20` to setting `C++ Language Dialect`.

Comment: Visual Studio 2019 (latest version 16.10, on Windows) is the only IDE currently coming with a compiler that *fully* supports C++20. Clang and GCC are still missing features.

Comment: Note that you have to change default settings to enable C++20 - I think this is your main problem. Go to your project setting / "Build settings" tab / find option "C++ Language Dialect" and provide value "-std=c++20" (option is not available in drop down menu). Xcode do not provides C++20 selection since support of this standard is still quite poor.

Comment: In the past it made sense to call XCode a compiler as it has it's own patched clang version with undocumented feature difference set from clang. But with XCode 13 it seems to be an offical release with "clang 13" as a base. But the standard library is still different.

Answer (score 3):

Here can you find the currently implemented feature support of the GCC compiler of the C++20 specification:
[GCC Link](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx20)

But you need to enable it in your console command or add this to your toolchain: "-std=c++20"

Answer (score 2):

gcc version 8 and up supports some of C++20; you can try using that.

It should also be noted that Xcode isn't a compiler, but instead an IDE that should be using clang as the actual compiler. Clang also currently has support for some of the C++ 20 features. To use them the -std=c++20 flag will still be needed.

Comment: Version 8? 8 may support *some* of C++20, but [according to this chart, it's not that much of it](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/20).

Comment: @NicolBolas you are correct. I initially meant to write in my reply that it was limited support, but forgot. I've edited that in.

Comment: Why recommend gcc 8 when the current release is 11.1 ?  Current 3 major compilers on godbolt - https://godbolt.org/z/Gn3M4zv37  Also reference [C++ compiler support - C++20 features](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support#cpp20)